# Syntax error when declaring a variable

Tags: python, variables, math

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWSIc.png
when I run this code:

```
import turtle
import math
pi = math.pi
def triangle(a,b,c):
    # law of cosines, where ac = angle c
    ac = math.acos(a**2 + b**2 - c**2/(2*a*b)*180/pi
    # law of sines
    ab = math.asin(math.sin(ac)/c*b)*180/pi     
    # Angle sum theorem
    aa = 180 - (ab + ac)

    lengths = [a,b,c]
    angles = [ac,aa,ab]

    for n in range 3:
        turtle.forward(lengths[n])
        turtle.left(180-angles[n])
triangle(3,4,5)'
```

Sublimetext 3 returns:

```
File "C:\Users\chul\Documents\GitHub\One-Python-Project-Per-Day\April\18 triangle.py", line 10
ab = math.asin(math.sin(ac)/c*b)*180/pi     
 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Can anybody explain what is going on?

Comment: `ac = math.acos(a**2 + b**2 - c**2/(2*a*b)*180/pi) # <----` :-(

Comment: Also, I think your formula is incorrect, you should have additional parentheses over the numerator : `(a ** 2 + b ** 2 - c ** 2)`

Comment: You are missing a parenthesis

Comment: Any decent IDE or programming editor would show you the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your

```
ac = math.acos(a**2 + b**2 - c**2/(2*a*b)*180/pi
```

is missing a end bracket:

```
ac = math.acos(a**2 + b**2 - c**2/(2*a*b)*180/pi)
```